# How to add methods or props to a functions?

Tags: javascript

How to add methods or props to a functions?

Following is a function:

```
function testFunction()  {
  console.log('test')
}
```

Like this:
[image]

So you can see a lot of methods like apply, bind,call and properties like arguments, caller,length etc...

How can I add a static method or property to my function like this:

```
testFunction.someMethod() {

}
```

Such that it will be available in the above mentioned list.

I;m not talking about `function.prototype`. I know it is possible. I just wanted to know if custom static methods (like bind,call or apply) are creatable such that it will be avaialable in the above mentioned list.

Comment: Will it be available along with the methods like bind,call or apply and properties like arguments, caller,length as a list when I use the intellisense

Comment: function testFunction  {
  console.log('test')
} are there no parenthesis ?

Comment: testFunction.prototype.methods = () => console.log('hello world!')

Comment: But those methods come from the function prototype, so the question makes no sense without that

Comment: Not exacly but. It's possible

Comment: Really does that methods comes from the prototype?

Comment: Yes, they're inherited.

Comment: So any methods that I create will be available as a list the I add a period after the function ( i.e. the intelligence list)

Comment: How can I add more methods like those? Do I need to extend the function (the original definition of Function Symbol)?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You need to work from the symbols.

Comment: This is not a common thing to do. I'd say it's better to use a class instead or take a different approach. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 2):

```
function testFunction()  {
  console.log('test')
}
testFunction.someMethod = function() {
  console.log('some method');
}

testFunction.someMethod();
```

[image: code]

This is not a common thing to do. I'd say it's better to use a class instead or take a different approach.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes